# Quoting in macro-defining macro

Tags: common-lisp, lisp-macros, backquote

I'm trying to write a macro that defines some helpers for struct-of-arrays data structure (based on [this](https://gist.github.com/guicho271828/22b30038f3e2fdf984338b33fe585418) snippet). Inside that macro I define another macro that helps with traversing all of the slot values in struct. The thing is I can't make double unquoting work properly. Here's the code:

```cl
(defmacro defcomponent (name-and-options &body slots)
  (setf name-and-options (ensure-list name-and-options))
  (let ((struct (first name-and-options))
        (slot-names (iter (for s in slots)
                          (collecting
                           (ematch s
                             ((or (and name (symbol)
                                       (<> _ '*)
                                       (<> _ nil))
                                  (list* name _ (plist :type _ :read-only _)))
                              name))))))
    `(progn (defstruct ,name-and-options
              ;; some task-specific stuff omitted here
              )
            (defmacro ,(symbolicate 'with- struct) (components &rest body)
              `(loop
                 ,@',(iter (for s in slot-names)
                          (appending `(for ,s across (,(symbolicate struct '- s) components))))
                 do ,@body)))))
```

So for instance `(defcomponent buzz x y)` macroexpands to

```cl
(PROGN
 (DEFSTRUCT (BUZZ)
   X Y)  ;; details omitted
 (DEFMACRO WITH-BUZZ (COMPONENTS &REST BODY)
   `(LOOP ,@'(FOR X ACROSS (BUZZ-X COMPONENTS) FOR Y ACROSS (BUZZ-Y COMPONENTS))
          DO ,@BODY))
```

which kinda works, but I want to access `components` parameter of the internal `with-buzz` macro, i.e. something like this

```cl
(DEFMACRO WITH-BUZZ (COMPONENTS &REST BODY)
   `(LOOP FOR X ACROSS (BUZZ-X ,COMPONENTS) FOR Y ACROSS (BUZZ-Y ,COMPONENTS)
          DO ,@BODY))
```

How do I possibly acheive that? I've tried a lot of the combinations of `,` and `,@` to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes it helps not to work with backquote patterns. Then scope problems can be easier understood with the help of a compiler, which would warn about the usual variable scope problems.

As a slightly simplified exercise, we will write a function, which generates code. The generated code is a macro definition, which itself generates code.

```
(defun makeit (name slots)
  (labels ((symbolicate (pattern &rest things)
             (intern (apply #'format nil pattern things)))
           (compute-for-clauses (slots)
             (loop for s in slots
                   append (list ''for (list 'quote s)
                                ''across (list 'list
                                               (list 'quote
                                                     (symbolicate "~a-~a" name s))
                                               'components)))))

    (list 'progn
          (list 'defmacro
                (symbolicate "WITH-~a" name)
                '(components &rest body)
                (append '(list* 'loop)
                        (compute-for-clauses slots)
                        (list ''do 'body))))))
```

Example

```
CL-USER 51 > (pprint (makeit 'buzz '(x y)))

(PROGN
  (DEFMACRO WITH-BUZZ (COMPONENTS &REST BODY)
    (LIST* 'LOOP
           'FOR
           'X
           'ACROSS
           (LIST 'BUZZ-X COMPONENTS)
           'FOR
           'Y
           'ACROSS
           (LIST 'BUZZ-Y COMPONENTS)
           'DO
           BODY)))

CL-USER 52 > (eval *)
NIL

CL-USER 53 > (macroexpand-1 '(with-buzz a (+ 12) (+ 30)))
(LOOP FOR X ACROSS (BUZZ-X A) FOR Y ACROSS (BUZZ-Y A) DO (+ 12) (+ 30))
T
```

Answer (score 0):

All right, I've managed to do it by resorting to manual list construction + `eval` instead of quasiquoting, but sweet mother of god it looks so hakish.

```cl
;; skip
(defmacro ,(symbolicate 'with- struct) (components &rest body)
    (append
    '(loop)
    (eval
    `(iter (for s in ',',slot-names)
            (appending `(for ,s across (,(symbolicate ',',struct '- ,'s) ,,components)))))
    '(do)
    body))
```

I'll gladly accept any other answer solving the problem more idiomatically.